# Python collapsing a list of "pandas.core.series.Series" into a dataframe from map call

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and I hope that someone can help me get a handle on `map`.
I have a function `myfunc` which takes a column in a dataframe and for every column creates a calculation that results in a JSON which I then convert to a data-frame. Below is pseudo-code for what I'm doing.

For example

```
def myfunc (factor):
    
    # This is the API we are posting to
    str_url = "www.foourl.com"

    # This is the factor we post to try and get the result
    request_string = [{"foo":factor}]
          
    header = {"content-type": "application/json","AUTH-TOKEN": "Foo"}
    # We post it using our authorization and Token
    response = requests.post(str_url , data=json.dumps(request_string), headers=header)
    
    # convert response to json format and then to the dataframe
    results_json = response.json()
    return(pd.json_normalize(results_json))
```

I then execute my function using the below code which works perfectly. I can access each result using result[1] to get the dataframe results for factor[1], results[2] for factor[2] and so on. It returns a <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

```
# Import in the excel sheet and get the factors
df = pd.read_excel ('ref_data/search_factors.xlsx')
test = df['factor_number']

# Run the API for every factor
# Collapse the list then into a dataframe
result = test.map(myfunc)
```

My question is

> Since all the results are dataframes and are exactly the same structure wise (5 columns all with the same name), Is there a way I can just collapse everything into a single data-frame after all the iterations from map

I know for example in `R` you can use bind_rows in `dplyr` or something like `map_df` to do the same thing. Is their an equivalent in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in `pandas` we have `concat`

```
df=pd.concat(result.tolist())
```